# How to implement QLearning?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, markov-process

I know that v10 has support for both Machine Learning and Finite Markov Processes, the Q-learning algorithm uses both. Specifically, Q-learning  finds an optimal action-selection policy for any given (finite) Markov decision process (MDP).

*Are there any specific combinations of functions and options that I should use as a starting point? or should I do this from scratch?*

Answer (score 12):

Right now you can use [MDPtoolbox](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MDPtoolbox/index.html) via RLink.

Reinforcement learning is expected in the next version of Mathematica. You can see [this presentation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9280/) from the Wolfram Conference 2015. A lot of interesting things are expected in the machine learning functionality (slides 10, 11 or images below).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please give a minimal work code example using nettrains?

Comment: @M.R. [link1](https://github.com/ianfanx/wss2018Project/tree/master/Project) and [link2](https://github.com/b19e93n/ShanWolframSummer-2018/tree/master/Project)