# How to make Advanced Activations Layers in Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to try [Advanced Activations Layers](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/) in `Mathematica`,but not found.

So I try to use `ElementwiseLayer` to implement it.

*Thank you @nikie*,`LeakyReLU`,`ELU`,`ThresholdedReLU` can be written like this.

`LeakyReLU` : `ElementwiseLayer[Ramp[#] - Ramp[-#]*0.3 &]`

`ELU` : `ElementwiseLayer[Ramp[#] - Ramp[-#]/#*(Exp[#] - 1) &]`

`ThresholdedReLU` : `ElementwiseLayer[Ramp[# - 1]/(# - 1)*Ramp[#] &]`

`PReLU` has a learned parameter `alpha`，but I don't know how to train the net ...

```
graph = NetGraph[{ConstantArrayLayer["Array" -> ConstantArray[0.3, 5]], ThreadingLayer[Ramp[#] - Ramp[-#]*#2 &]}, {{NetPort["Input"], 1} -> 2}]
graph[{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}](*{-0.3, -0.15, 0., 0.5, 1.}*)
```

[image]

Is there any more simple method to make Advanced Activations Layers?

***Application***: [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141598/object-detection-and-localization-using-neural-network) used `leayReLU[alpha_] := ElementwiseLayer[Ramp[#] - alpha*Ramp[-#] &]`

Comment: Setting `Attribute` to `Listable` seems to be the problem. You can try with `Function` directly: `g = Function[x, Piecewise[{{0.3*x, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], Listable]`

Comment: @AnjanKumar Thank you,I edit my question.

Comment: Regarding the learned parameter of `PReLU`, I think you need to use `ConstantArrayLayer` for learned constants, and (I guess) `ThreadingLayer` to combine input from the constant and the "data" input layers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation of [`ElementwiseLayer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ElementwiseLayer.html) explicitly lists which functions are allowed, and `UnitStep` is not in this list, I believe that's why the function fails.

Simple workaround: Use a combination of functions from that list, like `Ramp`:

```
f = Ramp[#] - Ramp[-#]*0.3 &;

l = ElementwiseLayer[f]
l[{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}]
```

> {-0.3, -0.15, 0., 0.5, 1.}

Answer (score 4):

This is how to constract a `PReLU`

```
data = Thread[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}] -> RandomReal[1, {100, 3}]];
net = NetGraph[{5, ConstantArrayLayer["Output" -> 1], 
         ReplicateLayer[5], FlattenLayer[], 
         ThreadingLayer[Ramp[#1] - #2*Ramp[-#1] &], 3}, 
         {NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> 5 -> 6, 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}]
```

[image]

```
NetTrain[net, data, MaxTrainingRounds -> 100, BatchSize -> 32];
(*well done*)
```

In 11.2,mma provide more **Advanced Activations Layers**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In 2020, the function `ParametricRampLayer` was introduced to implement leaky ReLU layers. The slope can be either hard-coded or learned.