# How do I create my own activation function in NetChain in Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to have my own activation function, say a quadratic function, instead of Tanh, or Sigmoid etc. in Mathematica. How do I insert it in NetChain?
e.g., how will the below code look for a new activation function?

```
net = NetChain[{10, Tanh, 10, Tanh, 10, Tanh, 10, Tanh, 1}, 
   "Input" -> "Scalar", "Output" -> "Scalar"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly duplicate question: [How to make Advanced Activations Layers in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146569/17).

Comment: I think you're looking for `ElementwiseLayer`. In v12, it also supports common activation functions like SELU etc.

Comment: It also supports those shorthand named functions in 11.3 (and 11.2, I think) :)

Answer (score 1):

You want `ElementwiseLayer`. For example, here's how to define a leaky ReLU activation layer:

```
leakyRelu[α_] := ElementwiseLayer[
  If[# > 0, #, α #] &
  ]
```

We can see that this works:

```
Plot[leakyRelu[.3][x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

You might use it like so in your network:

```
net = NetChain[{10, leakyRelu[.3], 10, leakyRelu[.3], 10, leakyRelu[.3], 10, leakyRelu[.1], 1}, "Input" -> "Scalar", "Output" -> "Scalar"]]
```

You can add a reasonable amount of logic within the `ElementwiseLayer`, though there are a lot of symbols that won't work (for instance, you can't use `ImageIdentify` within your activation layer, but you can use `Ramp`, `LogisticSigmoid`, `Tanh`, `ArcTan`, `ArcTanh`, `Sin`, `Sinh`, `ArcSin`, `ArcSinh`, `Cos`, `Cosh`, `ArcCos`, `ArcCosh`, `Log`, `Exp`, `Sqrt`, `Abs`, `Gamma`, `LogGamma`... 
An incomplete list is in the documentation for `ElementwiseLayer`.

---

Regarding your comment with more information: Assuming you want to have `a` `b` and `c` configurable, you can do:

```
yourActivation[a_, b_, c_] := ElementwiseLayer[
  a #^2 + b # + c &
  ]
```

and then you can use it in a `NetChain` like so:

```
net = NetChain[{10, yourActivation[.3, .4, .1], 10, 1}, 
  "Input" -> "Scalar", "Output" -> "Scalar"]
```

Comment: what is alpha here? What is the expression of the function you are using? I am looking for activation function of f[x] = a x^2 + b x + c.

Comment: Alpha is just a configurable weight - look up the Leaky ReLU activation function for more information about it. What is a, b, and c in your function?

Comment: @jjal See my edit