# Rectangular object boundary detection

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I would like to find the boundaries of an object:

[image]

I have looked that the YOLO algorithm but it looks like [the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwO3X.jpg) cut off parts of the object a lot. What kind of algorithm can I use to achieve this result? How can I train a neural net to recognize these bounding boxes?

Comment: and how does this relate to the software mathematica?

Comment: related  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141598/2079